# Does Require.js have a sync version for loading a single dependency?

Tags: javascript, browser, requirejs

… which would enable this pattern:

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

I'm looking at the [Require.js docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) and all I can see is the callback-version, e.g. `require(['jQuery'], function ($) { … });`

Comment: Afaik the "sync" version only works in node.js and when the script has been loaded before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the sync variant is used during development:

> `require('foo')` performs a synchronous load, `require('foo', function(foo){ … })` performs an asynchronous load. In development we use the sync load (convenience being the only reason) - in production the RequireJS Optimizer inlines that require-call anyway…

Source: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill/issues/18#issuecomment-55604581

Answer (score 1):

Require comes with a 'CommonJS' mode for allowing Node-like require statements inline in your code.  For example, this is a typical AMD definition that will load these scripts asynchronously:

```
define(['script1', 'script2'], function (script1, script2) {

});
```

But you can also do this:

```
define(function () {

   var script1 = require("script1");
   var script2 = require("script2");
});
```

And Require will process these asynchronously also.  The way it does that is that Require sees that you haven't specified an array of dependencies as the first argument and then scans your code for Require statements.  It then processes each of them asynchronously.

However, to answer your question, if you DO specify a dependency array as the first parameter and still use CommonJS syntax, Require will process the require statements synchronously:

```
define([], function () {

    // Each of these scripts will be loaded synchronously
    var script1 = require("script1");
    var script2 = require("script2");
});
```

Documentation::

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define

Answer (score 0):

Limited by the browser, loading scripts can only be async. So there's not a sync version for loading dependencies in Require.js.

However, some module loaders do have workarounds. For example, Sea.js offer a sync version(http://seajs.org/docs/en.html#quick-start) by running a regexp to extract all dependencies(https://github.com/seajs/seajs/blob/3d3c3bc142d9a6e3f6de14c1959d3f308b1c9e0e/src/module.js#L324) and loading them asynchronously before actually executing the script. So it seems that the dependencies are loaded synchronously.